# R Shiny- how to search multiple user input string in file

Tags: r, shiny

I have data in input file with a "comment" column, and I want to display results based on search string.

Example of string:

> Collecting data is good and collecting Big Data is better While
>   applications of ElasticSearch have advanced to Machine Learning
>   ElasticSearch is used for web search ...

When user provides search string `Collecting have`, results should be:

> **Collecting** data is good and collecting Big Data is better While applications of ElasticSearch **have** advanced to Machine Learning

Comment: column:                                                                                             
 Collecting data is good and collecting Big Data is better                       
 While applications of ElasticSearch have advanced to Machine Learning ElasticSearch is used for web search .. .. ..

Comment: Please show your code by updating in the post and where exactly you need help in that code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and edit your question to show what you tried, and give us some data example we can use to help you.